# Facebook Session not destroying in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

I am developing the application of login using facebook in Zend Framework. I done the login code and fetch its data properly. But now I want to ask that how to destroy facebook session bcoz its not destroying until I close the browser. I want to make logout code. Thank you...

Comment: Use this it would remove the all sessions<?php  @session_destroy(); ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use session_destroy() if you are using normal php session. But if you are using Zend_Session_Namespace() then you can unset it like:

$session=new Zend_Session_Namespace('namespace_name');

$session->unsetAll();

It will unset all the variable in particular namespace.